# Copying a text file into a 2D char array in java

Tags: java

I'm working on reading a text file that contains an 5x6 character big ascii image. Here's what i've done so far:

```
  ...    
  Scanner fileReader = null;
  try{
     File file = new File(fileName);
     fileReader = new Scanner(file);
     int offset = 0;

     char [][] pic = new char[5][6];

     while (fileReader.hasNextLine()){
        for (int u = 0; u < row; u++){
           for (int i = 0; i < col; i++){
              String line = fileReader.nextLine();
              pic[u][i] = line.charAt(offset++);
           }
        }
        return pic;
     }
     fileReader.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }...
```

This gives me a "no line found" message. I'm wondering if the scanner i use to ask the user the name of the file is a part of the problem. Here's what that looks like:

```
  System.out.println("Hello! I load files.");
  System.out.println("Please, enter file name:");
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  String fileName = reader.nextLine();
```

I've tried to close the reader after but it didn't change anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing an error message / exception stacktrace? If so, post the *full* text, and indicate which lines of code you've posted are involved.

Comment: @samkayoki  can you try by hard coding the file path.

Comment: This is a part of my school work so I use the schools automatic checker to see if it's correct and it only gives me that message. I don't have the text file on my computer and i wouldn't know how to open it if I did. If i try it, it just tells me "(No such file or directory)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things :

First, you are attempting to read a line for each index of your array (that is `row*col` times).

Second, you should only read a line by row.

You may replace your whole `while` loop with this :

```
    for (int u = 0; u < row && fileReader.hasNextLine(); u++) {

        String line = fileReader.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++) {

            pic[u][i] = line.charAt(offset++);
        }

        offset = 0;
    }
    return pic;
```

Also , you probably want to reset the value of `offset` after each processed "row".

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I need to return this as a part of an assignment but the automatic checker now tells me "END OF FILE"  instead of accepting the code, but that probably not something people who haven't used it can help me with.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner (new File("file.txt"));
int i = 0;
char[][] pic = new char[5][];
while (fileReader.hasNextLine()){
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    pic[i] = line.toCharArray();
    i++;
}
fileReader.close();
```

I tried it with seuqnce and worked:

```
 Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(fileReader.nextLine());
    fileReader.close();

    fileReader = new Scanner (new File("file.txt"));
    int i = 0;
    char[][] pic = new char[5][];
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()){
        String line = fileReader.nextLine();
        pic[i] = line.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(line);
        i++;
    }
    fileReader .close();
```

output:

> sadsadd sadsadd
>
> sadasdasdasdsad sadasdasdsadsa sadasdasdsadsadsa dAS dASd

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I should have clarified in my post I have to use Scanner. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Samkayoki it's not that different though, I'll revise my answer